# AngularJS - applying class dynamically on $render inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, render

I'm trying to add a class to a input tag dynamically depending on a condition, inside a directive. Something like that:

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, model) {
    model.$render = function () {

    if (verify(model.$modelValue)) {
        var elm = getElm(element)

        elm.addClass('default');
      } 
    } 
  }
```

But if element is an input, then the value is not displayed in the view.

Any guesses about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Based on the updated requirements from the comments, we can add async validators to also add the class.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.test = "asdf";
  })
  .directive('checkAvailability', function checkAvailabilityFunc($q) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$asyncValidators.userExist  = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          if (modelValue === 'asdf') {
            element.parent().addClass('default');
            deferred.resolve();
          } else {
            element.parent().removeClass('default');
            deferred.reject();
          }
          return deferred.promise;
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.default {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <div style="padding:10px;display:inline-block;">
    <input type="text" ng-model="test" check-availability>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I am not sure why you have gone to the complex `$render` for this requirement, please check my below example where we can use `ng-class` and achieve the same. To know more about `ng-class` visit [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.test = "asdf";
});
```

```css
.default {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-class="{ 'default' : test === 'asdf' }">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Naren, thanks for replying. 
The thing is that I need to add this to 100+ fields depending on a validation. Besides, the class may not be applied to the input element but to one of its parents

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't know about $asyncValidators. Your solution is really ingenious

Comment: I had some issues with $asyncValidators so trying $validators went better